# Event when IFrame has posted back?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that closes a modal in the parent when an IFrame's button is pressed.

This works well, but my problem is I need the IFrame to be fully postbacked before executing the close method.

```
var $MyFrame = $("#editScheduleFrame");

// You need to wait for the iFrame content to load first
// So, that the click events work properly
$MyFrame.load(function () {
    var frameBody = $MyFrame.contents().find('body');
    var btn = frameBody.find('.schedule-submit');

    btn.on('click', function () {
        closeEditModal();
    });
});
```

Is there any way I can instead call closeEditModal only once the schedule submit button has been pressed AND the IFrame child page has posted back?

Comment: How do you determine if a page load is a post back? You should have a property/attribute for that.

Comment: No, the page has an IFrame, when I click the IFrame's button it postback the iframe but not the parent, I want it to close the modal of the parent that the IFrame is in after the child postback.

Comment: This has to all be done via Javascript, no CodeBehind.

Comment: How about after a postback occurs in the child (and it's ready to tell the parent it's done), it puts Javascript on its page that's basically: `window.parent.closeEditModal();`?

Comment: It might not have a parent. There must be some way to control this from the parent though...

Comment: @Milo What I'm saying is, the script on the server should somehow denote the page is a post back. It can be as simple as writing a content attribute: `<body data-postback="true">`. Then you can detect that with JavaScript and act accordingly.

Comment: Can you put that last one in the form of an answer?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas But what's the event that should be listened for? When the button is clicked, you can obviously listen for that, but then what? How do you know when the postback is done?

Comment: @Ian The "load" event (or better: "DOMContentLoaded"). The "click" doesn't matter as you have to wait for the page to re-load anyway. The server could write stuff like: `<body data-postback="true" data-init-action="closeEditModal">`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Hmm I could've sworn the `load` event didn't fire more than once in the parent page. I think I'm thinking of cross-domain iframes. And what I meant about the "click" event was that they were already using it and it wasn't enough, just pointing it out. I understood exactly what you meant by the `data-*` attributes being written, I just didn't know you could listen for the actual `load` event of the inner window.

Comment: @Ian Not the "load" event of the parent page. It's the child page that is post-backed. Also, it's not the parent that would listen to the "load" event of the child page, it's the child itself which would listen to its own "load" event. So, the user clicks on a button in the child page. Then that child page does a post back, and after that, i.e. on "load", the child closed the parent's modal dialog.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I know. The child page posts back. On post back, the server will write a `data-*` attribute to the `<body>` tag. But the parent page has to listen for the child page's `load` event, like the OP already is - `$MyFrame.load(function () { });` will fire for every time the iframe is loaded. The OP already said they don't want to fire it from the child - the parent has to be the listener.

Comment: @Ian Ah, yes. I see. Well, the `<iframe>` *does* fire a "load" event every time a page loads in it (including post-backs), so the parent will be able to detect the post-back.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Exactly. And I didn't know this before. But I'm still pretty sure that cross-domain iframes don't fire the "load" event every time the page loads. I may be wrong though. Not important for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script on the server should somehow denote the page is a post back. It can be as simple as writing a content attribute: `<body data-postback="true">`. Then you can detect that with JavaScript and act accordingly.